# Locate an element using selenium xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium3, selenium4

I am trying to locate an element that has the following line in the chrome inspect code, `<href="app/arp/home/profile">`.

My line is:

```
driver.find_element(By.xpath("//a[@href='/app/arp/home/profile']")).click()
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'xpath'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How about trying `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/app/arp/home/profile']")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Till [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) **v3.141.0** to locate an element using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you can use the following syntax:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/app/arp/home/profile']")
```

However, in the upcoming releases [*`find_element_by_*` commands will be deprecated*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath)

```
def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
    """
    Finds an element by xpath.

    :Args:
     - xpath - The xpath locator of the element to find.

    :Returns:
     - WebElement - the element if it was found

    :Raises:
     - NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn't found

    :Usage:
        ::

            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    """
    warnings.warn("find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead")
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

From Selenium **v4.x** onwards the effective syntax will be:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/app/arp/home/profile']")
```

An example:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
  print(element)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="04a9fac269c3a9cb724cc72769aed4e0", element="1b8ee8d0-b26a-4c67-be10-615286a4d427")>
  ```

Comment: This is news to me!!! I've been using the By class mainly in Java what is the reason for the deprecation?

Comment: @MosheSlavin Give me some time, let me try to pull out the discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one

> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/app/arp/home/profile']")

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'xpath'.

This means you didn't import the correct object `By`.

Make sure to add the `import` on the top of the page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```